# geth console mining - how to find when a contract is mined

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain

I created a private blockchain console with an unlocked account.

I have a simple contract, **simpleContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() constant returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

It was made into a js file using

```
echo "var simpleOutput=`solc --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,interface simpleContract.sol`" > simpleStorage.js
```

I load my contract in the console using

```
loadScript("simpleStorage.js")
var simpleStorageContract = eth.contract(JSON.parse(simpleOutput.contracts["simpleContract.sol:SimpleStorage"].abi));
var simpleStorage = simpleStorageContract.new(   {     from: eth.accounts[0],      data: "0x" + simpleOutput.contracts["simpleContract.sol:SimpleStorage"].bin,      gas: '47000'   },  function (e, contract) { if(!e) {    if(!contract.address) {      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");    } else {      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);      console.log(contract);    }  }})
```

I see

> Contract transaction send: TransactionHash:
>   0x0f01f04f0e266cdca62479413bf17d65d38ef0b497dcbe9e9232451c994892a0
>   waiting to be mined...

When I start the miner with

```
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
miner.start(4)
```

It prints

> INFO [07-01|18:22:03] Updated mining threads    threads=4
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:03] Transaction pool price threshold updated
>   price=18000000000
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:03] Starting mining operation
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:03] Commit new mining work         number=3062 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=309.753µs
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:06] Successfully sealed new block            number=1 hash=a73c27…d68bae
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:06]  mined potential block                  number=2 hash=a73c27…d68bae
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:06] Commit new mining work                   number=3 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=126.412µs
>
> INFO [07-01|18:22:08] Successfully sealed new block            number=4 hash=577497…34db4e

How can I find when my contract will be mined? I was under the impression that I could find the block number using

```
eth.getTransaction
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

use the command web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash [, callback])
This will return in what block your transaction was mined or null if it's still pending.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction

If get Transaction return 'null' it mean the transactionHash is not mined. You can check local pending transactions with "eth.pendingTransactions"

Comment: I tried web3.eth.getTransaction("0x0f01f04f0e266cdca62479413bf17d65d38ef0b497dcbe9e9232451c994892a0")
it returned null

Comment: I ran the miner for over a few hours, I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) to check if a transaction was mined.

Comment: I tried web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x0f01f04f0e266cdca62479413bf17d65d38ef0b497dcbe9e9232451c994892a0") and get null. How much time does it take for it to be mined?

Comment: Are blocks being generated? Check with `web3.eth.blockNumber`. A block should generated each 15 seconds. If no blocks are generated then your difficulty is set too high in genesis.json. Lower it and reset your private blockchain.

Comment: I found the way around it. I increased the ether amounts and it went through. I wish it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial doing the same thing as you did.
 
https://medium.com/@tina26919742/a-complete-guide-on-building-a-smart-contract-on-a-private-net-in-ethereum-726851c7c044
But I see the contract is mined soon after miner.start (just a few seconds)
Can you provide more details on how you set up your private blockchain?
You can also append else console.log(e) to your callback function to see what happened.

Comment: I read your tutorial. It is outdated in one place. You have included the compiler inside the console, web3.eth.getCompilers() does not exist anymore. You have to compile outside and bring in the bin and abi files now.

Comment: yeah so I used geth version 1.5.9 instead of the latest, which still has the compiler. I do that because I think it may be better for beginners to follow. Maybe I should also include that in my tutorial. Thanks for the advice!